# How to use react-i18next translation outside a react component (non-component)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-hooks, react-context

I can use `useTranslation()` hook where I am importing this file, but I want know if there is a way to use translation in this file (vanilla JS).

```jsx
const children = [];

children.push(
  {
    path: "/coupons",
    name: "Coupons",
    component: AllCoupons,
  },
  {
    path: "/create",
    name: "Create Coupon",
    component: Coupon,
  }
);
```

The `component` property should be translatable [key].

Note: This is a file that exports routes.

Reference: [i18next.changeLanguage() changes only in-components locale, added by useTranslation #2171](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/2171#issue-1743791241)

Answer (score 0):

The internationalization of languages should be done in a `Json` file for each language. For example, if you are providing English and French languages in your website, respective `Json` files like `en.json` and `fr.json` should be created in the `src` folder of your application and then supplied to all the pages that need it.

You can make use of some library for that : [React i18next](https://react.i18next.com/)